# I need to annotate a large dataset in batches, so that each question is seen by 5 people

Tags: qualtrics

Basically say for e.g we have around 10,000 samples, and we need each instance/row to be annotated by 5 people.
Problem is , obviously we can't upload the entire dataset to the qualtrics portal, we need to find a reasonable chunk size, say 50 or 100 and then annotate in batches for 5 people.

Is there any provision in Qualtrics to make it in multi-batch format, bc the only other alternative I'm seeing is copy pasting 50 sizes of 200 or sth like that and keeping track of which ones done manually which is very tedious. If you get my query, can you help with that, it will mean a lot!